# passing a select list value to jquery autocomplete php file

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-autocomplete

There is no error in the code but the problem is when I type in product text filed after I select a option from brands it should pass the brand id but instead of that it pass "%" this but I want to pass 1,2 or 3 no matter which brand I selected it pass "%" this to the php file. I want know is there a way to pass changed brand id value to the php file

This is my code

```
$().ready(function(){
    $("#product").autocomplete("ajax/php/product_search.php?brands=" + $('#brands').val() +"&",
        {
            width: 260,
            matchContains: true,
            selectFirst: false,
            formatItem: function(data, i, n, value) {   
                return  value.split("|")[0];
            } 
        }
    );           
});
```

this is html select list for brands

```
<select id="brands" name="brands">
    <option value="%">-- Select --</option>
    <option value="1"> JVC - PLAYER SET </option>
    <option value="2"> CLARION - PLAYER SET </option>
    <option value="3"> DLS </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're constructing the URL when the page loads. If you want the URL to be dynamic, you have to provide a function that performs the AJAX call when the completion is requested.

```
$("#product").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
           $.getJSON("ajax/php/product_search.php",
                      { brands: $('#brands').val(),
                        term: request.term }, response);
        },
        width: 260,
        matchContains: true,
        selectFirst: false,
        formatItem: function(data, i, n, value) {   
            return  value.split("|")[0];
        } 
    }
);
```

Comment: thanks pal its works. I change my autocomplete jquery also to apply this method.